# Is it possible to display commands, executed with matlabcontrol's eval method?

Tags: java, matlab, matlabcontrol

Is it possible to display commands, executed with matlabcontrol's eval method?

For example, if I do

```
proxy.eval("A=2");
```

can I see input in Matlab, like

[image]